# xsl to remove specific attribute and add it as a child node instead

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<Envelope> 
  <ABC>
   <Hierarchy>
      <Family> 
       <History> ... </History>
      <Plan>  
       <Mom Name="Parent1">
         <Child Name = "Child11">
          <GrandChild Name="GC111" Label="" Sequence = "1">
            <Attributes>... </Attributes>
           </GrandChild>
          </Child>
         </Mom>
        <Child Name = "ChildIndependent1">
          <GrandChild Name="GCIndep12"   Label="&lt;Requested&gt;&lt;Item1&gt;68&lt;/Item1&gt;&lt;Item2&gt;69&lt;/Item2&g    t;&lt;/Requested&gt;" Sequence = "2" >
            <Attributes>... </Attributes>
        </GrandChild>       </Child>
  </Plan>      </Family>
   </Hierarchy>      </ABC>
</Envelope>
```

Here is my current xsl i have on the xml to create dummy mom tags around independent child tags. It also converts the & lt; and & gt; to < and >

```
         <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" >
         <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" use-character-maps="angle-brackets"/>
           <xsl:character-map name="angle-brackets">
           <xsl:output-character character="&lt;" string="&lt;"/>
           <xsl:output-character character="&gt;" string="&gt;"/>
         </xsl:character-map>
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="//ABC/Hierarchy/Family">
        <xsl:element name="Plan">
           <xsl:for-each select="//ABC/Hierarchy/Family/Plan/*">
              <xsl:if test="self::Mom">
                   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
              </xsl:if>
               <xsl:if test="self::Child">
                    <xsl:element name="Mom">
                       <xsl:attribute name="Name">dummy</xsl:attribute>
                         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
               </xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
       </xsl:template>
       </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I need to modify the above xsl to create the LabelRequested tag with the content of the label attribute as a child to the GrandChild and remove the Label attribute itself as below** above xsl already converts the & lt; and & gt; to < and >.

```
        <Child Name = "ChildIndependent1">
          <GrandChild Name="GCIndep12"    Sequence = "2" >
             <LabelRequested>
                        <Requested><Item1>68</Item1><Item2>69</Item2>   </Requested>
             </LabelRequested>
            <Attributes>... </Attributes>
        </GrandChild>
```

Any idea how I could change the above xsl to do this?

Comment: I cannot figure out what your question is. Please minimize the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem, and post the exact  output you want to get.

Comment: edited above question. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't see the expected output code.

Comment: This is what I expect                                                                                     <Child Name = "ChildIndependent1">
          <GrandChild Name="GCIndep12"    Sequence = "2" >
             <LabelRequested>
                        <Requested><Item1>68</Item1><Item2>69</Item2>   </Requested>
             </LabelRequested>
            <Attributes>... </Attributes>
        </GrandChild>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead. Note also that the stylesheet you have posted is not well-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To minimize the example to the problem at hand, consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GrandChild">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @Label"/>
        <LabelRequested>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Label" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </LabelRequested>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
   <ABC>
      <Hierarchy>
         <Family>
            <History> ... </History>
            <Plan>
               <Mom Name="Parent1">
                  <Child Name="Child11">
                     <GrandChild Name="GC111" Sequence="1">
                        <LabelRequested/>
                        <Attributes>... </Attributes>
                     </GrandChild>
                  </Child>
               </Mom>
               <Child Name="ChildIndependent1">
                  <GrandChild Name="GCIndep12" Sequence="2">
                     <LabelRequested><Requested><Item1>68</Item1><Item2>69</Item2></Requested></LabelRequested>
                     <Attributes>... </Attributes>
                  </GrandChild>
               </Child>
            </Plan>
         </Family>
      </Hierarchy>
   </ABC>
</Envelope>
```

Note that this assumes your processor supports `disable-output-escaping` and that the processing chain allows it to execute it. Otherwise you would have to use either XSLT 3.0 or an extension function to parse the markup contained in the `Label` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I have the above xsl on there is because this solution as is works but I am confused when it comes to where and how to embed this in my existing xsl that I have above. If I add this at the end, it does not work.

Comment: I had to put this on a server that has XSLT1.0 and does not support disable-output-escaping. Hence the &lt; and &gt; remain in the output instead of being converted to < and >. Any idea how I can work around this?

Comment: If your processor does not support DOE, then you have no way to unescape the markup. You could try and parse it using string functions, but that would be extremely tedious and error-prone. Look for solutions outside XSLT (or use another XSLT processor).